# How to set focus to a textbox that was just inserting it into my page?

Tags: castle-monorail, brail

I have a dynamic web page that after clicking a link, I insert a partial view into my page using brailjs action.  My brailjs view looks like this

```
page.inserthtml('bottom', 'items', { @partial: 'item/_fields_replacement_part' })
page.replacehtml('add_item_link', { @partial: 'item/_addlink_replacement_part' })
```

After I insert the html, I want to be able set focus to one of the textboxes that was just inserted.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have this js function:

```
function setFocus(id) {
   document.getElementById(id).focus();
}
```

You can call it from brailjs like this:

```
page.call('setFocus', 'myElementId');
```